# amazon application load balancer events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a load balancer with various machines underneath it - but of course it's possible that there might be none validly up and running at the moment a call comes in.

Is it possible to get some sort of event from the load balancer if that occurs - basically if there was a request for a url and nothing was around to validly service it?

(basically where I'm going with this is I want to have a set of boxes in an autoscaling group, but I want it to be able to scale down to 0, as these boxes may go weeks or months without being accessed... and then if a request comes through and isn't serviced - have a lambda function add a box to the group, and fire up)

Comment: Probably depends on what type of load balancer you are using. I think with an ELB you could look for backend errors in cloudwatch and then fire off a lambda funcation to change the ASGs desired count.

Comment: For an ALB, I think you could try the same strategy as an ELB or you could have a container running as a default rule on the ALB. The container could have a responder on it so the requesting user/service gets a message that says to retry in Xseconds. Then you modify the ASG.

Comment: *"these boxes may go weeks or months without being accessed"*  Perhaps they will not be accessed by expected requests, but they won't even go for hours without being accessed.  You'll see poorly managed search spiders and all kinds of random nonsense.